# Updating multiple counters in one query

Tags: cassandra, cql

My application currently does something like the following (minimal example):

```
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 1
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 2
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 2
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 3
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 3
```

However there are a few thousand updates per second, and at peak traffic it it too slow.

So I'd like to speed it up by combining the statements. The following of course does not work:

```
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

The `count`s of `2` and `3` would be wrong (1 instead of 2).

Do I manually have to split it into something like the following:

```
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
UPDATE counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE id IN (2, 3)
```

or is there a more clever way to do it in the statement directly?

Comment: if id is partition, your better off making different queries individually. Batching them together will ultimately hurt performance. A cluster should easily be able to handle thousands of writes a second so something else might be going on.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I tested both versions (isolated away from my actual application), and on the cluster used, there were about 3 times more counter increments per second possible with the bulk version. And yes, even with the non-bulk version, the number was in the thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another number than 1 to add to the count. (Functionally, you can; you'd have to test performance.)

```
cqlsh> UPDATE mykeyspace.counts SET count = count + 1 where k1=1;
cqlsh> UPDATE mykeyspace.counts SET count = count + 1 where k1=2;
cqlsh> UPDATE mykeyspace.counts SET count = count + 1 where k1=3;
cqlsh> select * from mykeyspace.counts ;

 k1 | count
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     1
  3 |     1

(3 rows)
cqlsh> UPDATE mykeyspace.counts SET count = count + 57 where k1=1;
cqlsh> select * from mykeyspace.counts ;

 k1 | count
----+-------
  1 |    58
  2 |     1
  3 |     1

(3 rows)
cqlsh> UPDATE mykeyspace.counts SET count = count + 65 where k1 in (2,3);
cqlsh> select * from mykeyspace.counts ;

 k1 | count
----+-------
  1 |    58
  2 |    66
  3 |    66
```